# MongoDB query update not working

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I used a query that works:

> db.getCollection('XXX').update(    {identifier: "123"}, //find
>   criteria    // this row contains fix with $set oper    { $set : {
>   migrated: "1"}} , { multi: true });

I would like to do the same in my API

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("identifier").is(123));

Update update = new Update();
update.set("migrated", "1");

mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, Person.class);
//        mongoOperations.updateMulti(query, update, Person.class);
```

but it doesn't work.

I tried to add @transactional, but it was not helpful. 
Some other queries like filndAll work properly.

Comment: Try `query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("identifier").is("123"));`

Comment: are there any errors.